# xaf C# show related business object as a listview on tab

Tags: c#, xaf

My business object(sms) has a one-to-many relationship with a business object (firm) from another module. So I established this association in module class's CustomizeTypesInfo method.

I debugged and I'm sure that this association is created but when I click my firm object I can't see the sms list. I want the sms list to open in a separate tab. How can I achieve this?

```
public override void CustomizeTypesInfo(ITypesInfo typesInfo)
{
base.CustomizeTypesInfo(typesInfo);
        ITypeInfo firmTypeInfo = typesInfo.FindTypeInfo(typeof(Firm));
        ITypeInfo smsReportTypeInfo = typesInfo.FindTypeInfo(typeof(Sms));
        IMemberInfo memberInfoSms = smsReportTypeInfo.FindMember("Firm");
        if (firmTypeInfo != null && smsReportTypeInfo != null)
        {
            XPDictionary xpDictionary = XpoTypesInfoHelper.GetXpoTypeInfoSource().XPDictionary;
            XPClassInfo firmClassInfo = xpDictionary.GetClassInfo("crm.net.Module", "crm.net.Module.BusinessObjects.Firm");
            if (firmTypeInfo.FindMember("SmsList") == null)
            {
                AssociationAttribute assoc1 = new AssociationAttribute("Firm_SmsReports", typeof(SmsReport));
                xpDictionary.GetClassInfo("crm.net.Module", "crm.net.Module.BusinessObjects.Firm").
                    CreateMember("SmsList", typeof(XPCollection<Sms>), true,
                        new AssociationAttribute(),
                        assoc1);
            }

            if (xpDictionary.GetClassInfo(typeof(Sms)).FindMember("Firm") != null)
            {
                if(memberInfoSms.FindAttribute<AssociationAttribute>() == null)
                    memberInfoSms.AddAttribute(new AssociationAttribute("Firm_SmsReports", typeof(Sms)));
            }

            XafTypesInfo.Instance.RefreshInfo(firmTypeInfo.GetType());
            XafTypesInfo.Instance.RefreshInfo(typeof(Sms));
            ((XafMemberInfo)memberInfoSms).Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the firm object have a property of type  Collection<sms>  ? or List<sms> or similar?

Comment: Yes I added that in module.cs class (CustomizeTypesInfo method)

Comment: is the property in the Firm class ? Can You type Firm.Messages.ToList() ?

Comment: I edited and added the code

Answer (score 0):

Open a Model Designer (at runtime) - find "Firm_DetailView".

check if it has a property "SmsList"
If not - add it manually in the model

Go to layout - and add that property to the layout